# How to join tables , query sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following  recipe database tables and their data .

how i can find the total number of recipes , number of category for each Ingredient ? I used many joining methods but i couldn't do the query i want.

I need as out put

Ingredient  id , how much recipe we can find this ingredient in, how much categories we can find this ingredients in.

**This is my attempt** 
The problem with my attempt is if i had ingredient who is in one recipe and in two categories
It will show in results that this ingredient is in 2 recipe , 2 categories

```
SELECT  
  I.idIng,COUNT(CI.idcat)AS "CAT FOR ING" , COUNT(RI.idRecipe )AS "RECETTE 
  FOR 
  ING" 
FROM
  INGREDIENT I
LEFT JOIN   
  Ingredient_Recipe RI  ON I.idIng = ri.idIng
RIGHT JOIN  
  Ingredient_Catigory CI ON I.idIng = CI.idIng
GROUP BY 
  I.idIng
ORDER BY
  I.idIng;
```

**Below is some test data:**

Here i created my category its will have many to many relation with Ingredient.

```
-- creating table cat category 
CREATE TABLE category (
idCat INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nomCat INT NOT NULL
);
```

Here i created my Recipe table its will have many to many relation with Ingredient.

```
-- creating table cat Recipe
CREATE TABLE Recipe(
idRecipe INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nameRecipe VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
);
```

This is my Ingredient table that will be link with both Recipe ,category .

```
-- creating table Ingredient
CREATE TABLE Ingredient(
idIng INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
nameIng VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
);
```

This is the intermediate table between Ingredient ,category because the relation is many to many.

```
-- creating table Ingredient_category
CREATE TABLE Ingredient_category (
idIng INT NOT NULL,
idCat INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT idIng_FK FOREIGN KEY (idIng) REFERENCES Ingredient(idIng),
CONSTRAINT idCat_FK FOREIGN KEY (idCat) REFERENCES category(idCat)
);
```

This is the intermediate table between Ingredient ,Recipe because the relation is many to many.

```
-- creating table Ingredient_Recipe
CREATE TABLE Ingredient_Recipe(
idIng INT NOT NULL,
idRecipe INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT idIngRecipe_FK FOREIGN KEY (idIng)    REFERENCES  
Ingredient(idIng),
CONSTRAINT idRecipe_FK FOREIGN KEY    (idRecipe) REFERENCES Recipe(idRecipe) 
);
```

Here we insert the data for testing.

```
-- insert data into  Recipe 
INSERT INTO Recipe VALUES(1,'SOUP');
INSERT INTO Recipe VALUES(2,'FRIED');
INSERT INTO Recipe VALUES(3,'BURGER');

-- insert data into  category 
INSERT INTO category VALUES(1,'VEGES');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(2,'DAIRY');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(3,'MEAT');
INSERT INTO category VALUES(4,'ANIMAL PRODUCT');

-- insert data into  Ingredient 
INSERT INTO Ingredient VALUES (1,'Eggs');
INSERT INTO Ingredient VALUES (2,'milk');
INSERT INTO Ingredient VALUES (3,'Beef');
INSERT INTO Ingredient VALUES (4,'chess');

-- insert data into  Ingredient_Catigory
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(1,4);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(2,4);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(3,3);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(3,4);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(4,2);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Catigory VALUES(4,4);


-- insert data into Ingredient_Recip
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Recipe VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Recipe VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Recipe VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Recipe VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO Ingredient_Recipe VALUES (3,2);
```

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Yep, show us your closest attempt and we'll help you fix it. You won't earn much if we just give you the answer.

Comment: Also, this is a decently asked question, gives us the schema and test data. Downvoters, think about whether this is a bad question or whether one part of the question has just been missed by op.

Comment: Please share your expected output

Comment: The output i need is Ingredient id , how much recipe we can find this ingredient in, how much categories we can find this ingredients in.

The problem with my attempt is if i had ingredient who is in one recipe and in two categories It will show in results that this ingredient is in 2 recipe , 2 categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT value)`, you're almost there. Try something like this;

```
SELECT  
  I.idIng,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CI.idCat)AS [Categories], 
  COUNT(DISTINCT RI.idRecipe)AS [Recipes] 
FROM #INGREDIENT I
LEFT JOIN #Ingredient_Recipe RI  ON I.idIng = ri.idIng
LEFT JOIN #Ingredient_Category CI ON I.idIng = CI.idIng
GROUP BY 
  I.idIng
ORDER BY
  I.idIng
```

The results look like this;

```
idIng   Categories  Recipes
1       1           2
2       2           1
3       2           2
4       2           0
```

Please note, I think a bit of the spelling was incorrect in the sample data but I've corrected it on my test system (and I've used #TempTables). I've changed your `RIGHT JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` (as a note, I've never seen a need to use `RIGHT JOIN` in production code, try to avoid them).

**Edit:** I've just noticed that this is now an Oracle question, the query above has only been tested on SQL Server although a cursory glance at the documentation shows that the syntax should be the same for Oracle too.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Ingredient_Recipe a join Ingredient_category b on a.idIng=b.idIng join Ingredient c on a.idIng=c.idIng join Recipe d on a.idRecipe=d.idRecipe join category e on b.idCat=e.idCat
```

try this out